# geom_errorbar transitions strangely with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate a scatterplot with bars representing standard deviation. My data are measurements taken over the course of several days. Using gganimate, I'm 99% of the way there, but the way the error bars are transitioning is not how I want.

[image: gif of a scatterplot with error bars, animated to transition between different time points of data.]

You can see that while the SD bars for the egg measurements transition smoothly, fading in and out, the SD bars for the larval measurements pop in and out of existence abruptly at both the beginning and end.

My data and code are below:

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(cowplot)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
library(rlang)
library(gganimate)
library(ggrepel)
library(MetBrewer)
library(gifski)

# Data:
longitudinalMeasurements <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          specimen = c("chunk1_L1","chunk1_L1",
                       "chunk1_E1","chunk1_E1","chunk1_E2","chunk1_E2",
                       "chunk1_E3","chunk1_E3","chunk2_E1","chunk2_E1","chunk2_E2",
                       "chunk2_E2","chunk2_E3","chunk2_E3","chunk2_E4",
                       "chunk2_E4","chunk2_E5","chunk2_E5","chunk2_E6","chunk2_E6",
                       "chunk3_L1","chunk3_L1","chunk3_E1","chunk3_E1",
                       "chunk3_E2","chunk3_E2","chunk3_E3","chunk3_E3",
                       "chunk3_E4","chunk3_E4","chunk3_E5","chunk3_E5","chunk3_E6",
                       "chunk3_E6","chunk4_L1","chunk4_L1","chunk4_L2",
                       "chunk4_L2","chunk4_E1","chunk4_E1","chunk4_E2","chunk4_E2",
                       "chunk4_E3","chunk4_E3","chunk4_E4","chunk4_E4",
                       "chunk4_E5","chunk4_E5","chunk4_E6","chunk4_E6",
                       "chunk4_E7","chunk4_E7","chunk4_E8","chunk4_E8","chunk4_E9",
                       "chunk4_E9","chunk4_E10","chunk4_E10",
                       "CSC02FK01H9M9C9_L1","CSC02FK01H9M9C9_L1","330_eggs_chunk1_L1",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_L1","330_eggs_chunk1_L2","330_eggs_chunk1_L2",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E3","330_eggs_chunk1_E3",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E4","330_eggs_chunk1_E4","330_eggs_chunk1_E5",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E5","330_eggs_chunk1_E6",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E6","330_eggs_chunk1_E7","330_eggs_chunk1_E7",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E8","330_eggs_chunk1_E8",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E9","330_eggs_chunk1_E9","330_eggs_chunk1_E10",
                       "330_eggs_chunk1_E10","330_eggs_chunk3_L1","330_eggs_chunk3_L1",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E1","330_eggs_chunk3_E1",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E2","330_eggs_chunk3_E2","330_eggs_chunk3_E3",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E3","330_eggs_chunk3_E4",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E4","330_eggs_chunk3_E5","330_eggs_chunk3_E5",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E6","330_eggs_chunk3_E6","330_eggs_chunk3_E7",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E7","330_eggs_chunk3_E8",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E8","330_eggs_chunk3_E9","330_eggs_chunk3_E9",
                       "330_eggs_chunk3_E10","330_eggs_chunk3_E10",
                       "330_eggs_chunk2_E1","330_eggs_chunk2_E1","330_eggs_chunk2_E2",
                       "330_eggs_chunk2_E2","330_eggs_chunk2_E3",
                       "330_eggs_chunk2_E3","330_eggs_chunk2_E4","330_eggs_chunk2_E4",
                       "330_eggs_chunk2_E5","330_eggs_chunk2_E5"),
       measurement = c("body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head",
                       "body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head","body","head","body","head","body","head","body",
                       "head"),
            Length = c(1.01,0.304,0.97,0.308,0.99,
                       0.299,0.94,0.342,0.832,0.291,0.949,0.27,0.914,
                       0.338,0.875,0.353,0.855,0.319,0.824,0.347,0.987,
                       0.159,0.92,0.283,0.923,0.327,0.92,0.272,0.825,0.286,
                       0.918,0.31,0.989,0.303,0.958,0.234,0.773,0.296,
                       1.003,0.299,0.891,0.334,0.963,0.322,0.83,0.29,
                       0.998,0.312,0.935,0.349,0.807,0.232,0.883,0.274,0.9,
                       0.336,0.955,0.314,1.065,0.161,1.098,0.292,1.104,
                       0.285,0.832,0.368,0.91,0.332,1.005,0.315,0.837,
                       0.364,0.912,0.257,0.889,0.366,0.891,0.332,0.968,
                       0.299,0.847,0.277,1.009,0.325,0.922,0.356,0.893,0.328,
                       0.947,0.336,0.877,0.379,0.932,0.304,0.936,0.319,
                       0.868,0.374,0.943,0.336,0.988,0.317,0.891,0.33,
                       0.899,0.305,0.882,0.328,0.963,0.295,0.965,0.308),
      observations = c("larva","larva","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "larva","larva","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","larva",
                       "larva","larva","larva","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","larva",
                       "larva","larva","larva","larva","larva","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","larva",
                       "larva","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg",
                       "egg","egg","egg","egg","egg","egg"),
              date = c("3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22",
                       "3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/29/22","3/28/22","3/28/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22","3/30/22",
                       "3/30/22")
)

# Pivoting to wider format:
longitudinalMeasurementsWider <- select(longitudinalMeasurements, 
                                  c(measurement, Length, specimen, observations, date)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(measurement),
              values_from = c(Length))

longitudinalMeasurementsWider$date <- as.Date(longitudinalMeasurementsWider$date,
                                              format = "%m/%d/%y")

# Getting SDs:
longitudinalSD <- plyr::ddply(longitudinalMeasurementsWider,
                           .(observations, date),
                           summarise, 
                           bodySD = sd(body),
                           headSD = sd(head),
                           bodyMean = mean(body),
                           headMean = mean(head))


# Plotting:
longitudinalPlot <- ggplot(data = longitudinalMeasurementsWider) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = body, 
                           y = head,
                           colour = observations,
                           group = date),
             size = 3) +
  geom_errorbarh(data = longitudinalSD,
                 aes(xmin = bodyMean - bodySD,
                     xmax = bodyMean + bodySD,
                     y = headMean,
                     colour = observations,
                     height = 0.01)) + 
  geom_errorbar(data = longitudinalSD,
                aes(ymin = headMean - headSD,
                    ymax = headMean + headSD,
                    x = bodyMean,
                    colour = observations)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=met.brewer("Redon", 7)) + 
  coord_trans(x="log10", 
              y="log10") + 
  ggtitle("Head width to body length") +
  xlab("Body length (log10, mm)") + 
  ylab("Head width (log10, mm)") + 
  transition_states(date,
                    transition_length = 1, 
                    state_length = 1, 
                    wrap = TRUE) + 
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

longitudinalPlot
```

I'm particularly stumped by the fact that one set of SD bars behaves, while the other does not. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for the behavior- it is because in my first time point for the larvae, I have only one observation, and so no calculated standard deviations. A hacky solution is to replace those `NA` values in `longitudinalSD` with `0`, like so:

```
longitudinalSD[is.na(longitudinalSD)] <- 0
```

I'd be interested if anyone has a more elegant solution, however!